# Conditions for an object to be called a variable

Tags: functions

> Consider the following function:
>   $$f(x)=x^2-2x-3 \equiv (x-3)(x+1) \tag{1}$$

We know that if $a$ denotes the solution to the equation $f(x)=0$, we have
$$f(a)=0 \tag{2}$$
$$a^2-2a-3=0 \tag{3}$$

so the two possible values of $a$ are $a=3$ and $a=-1$.

Going back to $(1)$ and differentiating with respect to $x$ we have
$$f'(x)=2x-2 \tag{4}$$

Setting $f'(x)$ to zero and let $f'(b)=0$, then

$$2b-2=0,  b=1 \tag{5}$$

---

Now turn to $(3)$ and treat $a$ as a (non-continuous) variable that takes only two values $a=-1$ and $a=3$, with $f(a)=a^2-2a-3$

Differentiating with respect to $a$ gives 
$$f'(a)=2a-2 \tag{6}$$
but by setting $f'(a)=0$, we get $a=1$ which is undefined in the given domain.

Therefore under such a construction, we cannot treat $a$ as a variable but it is merely a constant such that upon differentiation, $f'(a)$ is *identically* zero (i.e. $f(a) \equiv 0$ so $f'(a) \equiv 0$) ?

I cannot really distinguish between a constant and a variable here, what conceptual errors are present in my explanation?

---

Also, I've seen questions that go like this:

Let's $a$ denote the root of (1), show that

$$2a-2=0 \tag{7}$$
(which, according to the mark scheme, is obtained by differentiation?)

Comment: $f(x)$ is a function of variable $x$. The two values you have found are not the "roots" of an equation, but the point where the cartesian graph of the function intercepts $x$-axis.

Comment: *Equations* do not have roots.  Polynomials have roots.  Equations have solutions.

Comment: @Eric Towers Thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (6): This result is gibberish.  You have stated that $a$ is a variable that can only take two values.  Consequently, the limit required to evaluate the derivative, $f'(a)$, does not exist.

Also, your source for $a$, the solutions to $f(x) = 0$, make $a$ a constant.  This might be clearer if you don't reuse $a$ to mean multiple things.  In particular, let $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = -1$, and observe that your set of solutions is $\{a_1, a_2\}$.  That is, stop forcing $a$ to simultaneously represent two distinct values.

Then $f(a_1) = 0$ -- a constant function always producing the value zero -- and of course the derivative of a constant function with respect to any independent variable is zero.  Similarly, $f(a_2) = 0$ gives a zero derivative.

I don't make sense of your equation (7).  I would check this by plugging both choices for $a \in \{a_1,a_2\}$ into this equation to see if they work.  (They don't in this case but I interpret your particular (7) was a generic example, not an example intended to work with the given $f$).